# I want to make both Control keys as a Super key

Tags: xmodmap

I want to make both Control_L and Control_R as a Super key (Windows Key). Is this possible? I only made Control_R as a Super key but I could not make Control_L. Here is what I done.

```
xmodmap -e 'remove mod4 = Hyper_L'               

xmodmap -e 'add mod4 = Control_R'
```

This is xmodmap output:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Control_R (0x69),  Super_L (0x85),  Super_L (0xce)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

By the way, I made Caps_Lock as an additional Control_L, so I am not sure if this is the problem.